# Problema con Javascript y textarea

Tags: javascript, php, variables

Buenas noches a todos.

Tengo un pequeño problema con la inserción de datos mediante Javascript y textarea, os explico.

He creado un modal el cual tiene contenido para inscribirse a un training, la cuestión es que el usuario para inscribirse tiene que poner obligatoriamente un comentario, si no el JavaScript le dice que tu tía.

El código de a continuación esta realizado en un PHP, ya que es un modal. El identificador lo tomamos de un calendario. (Hasta aquí no hay ningún problema).

```
<textarea rows="3" id="comentario" name="comentario" class="resp" placeholder="Obligatorio introducir comentario..."></textarea></div>

<button type="button" id="singlebutton1" class="btn-u btn-u-primary" onClick="registerTraining('.$resultado_accesogen['t_vid'].','.$id.');">Inscribirse</button>';
```

El *button* envía el vid del usuario y el identificador del training al cual quiere inscribirse al **`modal.js`**. Una vez que se hace click en el botón, realiza la siguiente función:

```
function registerTraining(vid,id) {
    if (!$.trim($("#comentario").val())) { /* Si campo observaciones vacio */
        $("#comentario").addClass("error");     
    } else {
        ***var disponibilidad = $('#comentario').val();***
        console.log(disponibilidad);
        $.ajax({
            type    : "GET",
            url     : "/assets/php/bookTraining.php",
            dataType: "html",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1');
            },
            data    : {
                s: "book",
                vid: vid,
                id: id,
                disponibilidad : disponibilidad || ''
            },
    };
```

El problema que veo es donde esta en **`var disponibilidad = $('#comentario').val();`**, que no toma los datos del *textarea* para definirlo como la variable disponibilidad.

Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Por qué la etiqueta php? ¿Estas usando jQuery?

Comment: El textarea y el button, están en un php, de ahí que haya establecido la etiqueta PHP.

Comment: Considero que deberías mencionar eso en la pregunta. En cuanto a la inserción de datos ¿Dónde los quieres insertar?

Comment: @Rubén Añadido. Se van a insertar en una BBDD, que la función esta dentro de booktraining. Todos estos datos son cogido a través de un $_GET [nombre variable (vid, id, disponibilidad)]

Comment: Momento! estas pasando el contenido de un textarea por GET??

Comment: @jolsalazar  La cuestion es que no lo hago por un formulario, sino mediante una función en Javascript la cuál toma los demás datos n(id, vid)  sin ningún problema  ylos introduce perfectamente en la BBDD. El problema que estoy teniendo es con el textarea y disponibilidad. Que la variable no toma bien los datos del comentario.

Comment: @RobertoCeballosRamirez: Me parece que desbes simplicar tu pregunta. En [mcve] se indican sugerencias de como hacerlo.

Comment: @RobertoCeballosRamirez aún así. Independiente que no sea un formulario deberias enviarlo por POST, mas aun si es ingreso a la base de datos.

Comment: @jolsalazar Anteriormente lo he probado y no lo introduce por un $_POST, ya que el textarea no esta en un <form>. Voy a añadir mas código.

Comment: @Rubén He añadido todo el código que tengo ahora mismo para realizar esta función. Muchas gracias por la ayuda y el interés a todos

Comment: Mas que poner el TODO el código, la idea es que pongas **lo mínimo** necesario para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Pensaba en todo lo contrario, cuanto mas información mas fácil entender todo el proceso. He dejado el código mini y marcado donde falla. Gracias de nuevo

Comment: @RobertoCeballosRamirez puedes decirme que te arroja la consola del explorador cuando ejecutas `$('#comentario').length` fácil que ese modal está creando duplicados :)

Comment: @Davlio Ya he encontrado la solución al problema, muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal , te recomendaría hacer uso de javascript

```
        var disponibilidad = document.getElementById("comentario").value 
    if( $.trim(disponibilidad) == "" ){
    disponibilidad.className += " error";

    }else {
//continuar con el envío
}
```

Suponiendo que utilizaste un id  (id="comentario" ; como identificador único que no debe ser repetido en otro tag dentro de tu archivo php)

Saludos!

Comment: Solo tengo que decir muchisimas gracias compañero, me has venido al pelo. Cualquier cosa que necesites aqui estoy.